# Why my controller cannot get request from view?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to insert some data to database, I need id that I can get from my route and quantity. But my quantity keep define as null.
This is my view

```
<form  method="POST" action="{{ url('beli/'.$produk->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
              <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Jumlah Beli :</label>
                    <input type="name" class="form-control" name ="quantity" id="quantity" placeholder="Jumlah">
                  </div>
              
              <div class="mt-4">
                <div class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-flat">
                  <i class=" fa-lg mr-2"></i> <a href="{{url('/beli/'.$produk->id)}}">
                  Beli Produk </a>
                </div>
                </form>
```

and this is my Controller

```
public function tambah(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $idtoko = Store::select('id')->where('users_id',Auth::user()->id)->first();
        $transaksi = new Transaction();
        $transaksi->quantity = $request->get('quantity');
        $transaksi->stores_id = $idtoko->id;
        $transaksi->save();
    }
```

And this is my route
**Route::get('/beli/{id}','KeranjangController@tambah');**

Comment: Instead of $request->get('quantity') use $request->input('quantity', 0)

Comment: isn't it will add 0 value?

Comment: 0 is the default value if the input does not have value

Comment: but I mean I already insert the value in the view, but I can't get it's value

Comment: You are missing something or you are not explaining well your problem

Comment: You used `<input type="name" ...` for quantity input. But this is invalid. There is no `name` type for inputs. Change this to `number` or `text`. `<input type="number" ...` or `<input type="text" ...`